# 404 Not Found error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a database to store images and getting this error:
**The requested URL /storeinfo.php was not found on this server**
How can I remove this error?`

```
  <?php

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost:8080","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("imagestore",$conn);
    if(!$db)
    {
            echo mysql_error();
    }

    $rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];
    $image = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_s=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $q = "INSERT INTO studentdata VALUES('','$rollNo','$image','$image_s['mime']')";

    $r=mysql_query($q,$conn);
    if($r)
    {
            echo "Information stored successfully";
    }
    else
    {
            echo mysql_error();
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: By creating a file called `storeinfo.php` and putting in your web server's document root.

Comment: The code above is if the same file.

Comment: move your file into your server document root, if you are using fresh installed apache [lamp stack] this often by default will be /var/www/html/ , make sure of that by checking your apache configurations

Comment: The webserver has a document root where it searches for code to run. If you access `http://localhost/storeinfo.php` then `storeinfo.php` must be in the document root (in Ubuntu that's `/var/www/html` but it could also be in `/var/www/`) In windows it would be under `(W|M|X)AMP` install dir somewhere.